# Access route.data from app.component.ts

Tags: angular

I have a route set up like this in app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'faq',           component: FaqComponent, data:[{title:"FAQ"}]},
....]
```

I can access the data property from inside FaqComponent just fine.

```
export class FaqComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
       console.log("faq data-snapshot", this.route.snapshot.data);
  ...
```

What I want to do is access the data object from my main component(that contains the router) so I can set the title there somehow.

These are my currently not working efforts. Never does the data-object appear in the logs.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

     constructor(
             private route: ActivatedRoute,
             private router: Router) {

     }

     ngOnInit(): void {


       console.log("data-snapshot", this.route.snapshot.data);

       this.route.data.toPromise().then( data => {
         console.log("data", data);
       }, data=>{
         console.log("some problem with data", data);
       }); 

       this.router.events.subscribe(event=>{
        console.log("router event: ", event);
        if (event instanceof RoutesRecognized){
          let rec:RoutesRecognized = event;
          console.log("route rec data", rec.state.root.data);
        }  
       });

     }
```

Comment: app.component is not a route, so doesn't have access to the properties

Comment: You can either create service in between, or make the app component to be route